# Alter column script not working SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table, alter

I need to alter my column length, using below query i tried but the result was not what i expected

```
alter table clear.tbl_wlist_data_alias_dtls
  alter column entity_name nvarchar(500);
```

Earlier, the column size is 1200 [image: before executing query] and i tried to decrease it to 500 but after executing above query column length changed to 1000. [image: result after executing query]

Facing the same scenario even if i increase the column length.

My column is having constraint, is that restricting ??

Thanks in advance,
AnilSrinivas

Comment: Please post the output messages from SSMS when you run your `alter table` query. Please post the actual output from your `information_schema` query as text, not an unhelpful cropped screenshot.

Comment: Probably the `1000` is length in bytes. `nvarchar` is 2 bytes per character. But it will only use what the length of the string requires

Comment: What you think happened is not possible. Either you are looking at the wrong table (perhaps even the wrong database) or you did not refresh SSMS or someone is competing with you.

Comment: @SMor it is totally possible. the length is in bytes. This is an sp_help resultset https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#result-sets. or fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ed2f06757d099cb55af40c13ceb77204

Comment: (though of course they are misinterpreting the result)

Answer (score 0):

Tq @Martin, sp_help shows the actual size(in bytes) required by the column to store the data on the database. since column is of type nvarchar so it require double space to store the data hence it show the 1000 bytes as column length to store the 500 characters.

Answer (score -1):

If there is data already in the column, check the max length first on the data. Maybe you have data that exceeds the length you want to reduce to.

Comment: hai @Enem, i had max length 424

Comment: That is suggestion, not answer. And an attempt to change the maximum size to a value that is less than existing data will generate an error.